# AutoLayout on UILabels in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I want to set `AutoLayout` from storyboard on four `UILabel` inside a `UIView`, but they are not displayed perfectly as they should.

**My storyboard :**

[image]

Actually, Date, Subject, Max Marks, Marks Optd not show exactly.. I want to let them in the middle. It means, the gap between all labels are not same.

Comment: Can you please explain what exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually, Date, Subject, Max Marks, Marks Optd not show exacly..
i want to show in middle.  It means, the gap beween all label are not same..You can see that..

Comment: Can you also please provide an explanation of how you have added the constraints, what your view heirarchy is?

Comment: i have add left,right,top,bottom and fix width of all uilabel.

Comment: Select all your labels and give constraint `equal height` and `equal width`.